# Mocking or Stubbing Highcharts.Chart with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, highcharts, sinon

I am trying to mock or stub a Highcharts chart object using sinon.

```
let chart = sinon.mock(Highcharts.Chart);
chart.expects('getSVG').returns(mockSVG);
```

The error which is returned is:

```
[INFO]  TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getSVG as function
[INFO]      at <Jasmine>
[INFO]      at wrapMethod (node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:3692:21)
[INFO]      at Object.expects (node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:1701:13)
[INFO]      at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/test/js/core/test_exporting.js:13:15)
[INFO]      at <Jasmine>
```

getSVG is a method on chart - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#getSVG

I don't understand the error. Is it possible to mock or stub a Highchart chart. If not I would try to create a real one for my test.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the minimal completed code you want to test.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?